# VMware + Vista 64 = bluescreen?

Tags: vmware-workstation, bsod, windows-vista

I'm running a Windows Vista Business x64 laptop and my laptop seems to bluescreen (BSoD) after I install VMware (im using VMware Workstation 6.5). When I have VMware installed it always bluescreens on startup. So I'm already logged in then it bluescreens.

Is there any certain settings i have to configure or is there an issue with VMware compatibility with vista x64? Has anybody encountered a problem like this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: VMWare's support facilities are generally excellent, have you spoken with them yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used VMWare happily on Vista x64 with no probs - so probably best to go to VMWare support as Chopper3's comment suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem. It might be the same one you're having. Scott Hanselman blogged about it, but I can't post the link because I'm a new member.

My solution was to modify the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E96B-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\UpperFilters value to place the "vmkbd" driver at the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VMWare Workstation 6.5.2 on Vista x64 with no problems.

FYI - I have found that I cannot install the Checked / Debug versions of some OS in a VM - I get a bluescreen failure on the VM.   I have never had a bluescreen failure on the host.